# how to handle javascript alerts in selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium

So I there is this button I want to click and if it's the first time you've clicked it. A javascript alert popup will appear. I've been using firebug and just can't find where that javascript is located and I've tried

```
if EC.alert_is_present:
        driver.switch_to_alert().accept()
else:
    print("no alert")
```

the above code works if there is an alert box but will throw an error if there is none. even though there is an else statement I've even tried

```
   if EC.alert_is_present:
            driver.switch_to_alert().accept()
   elif not EC.alert_is_present:
               print("no alert")
```

it throws me this error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException: Message: No alert is present
```

how do we get around this?

Comment: Could this be the root cause? A bypassed call to fxdriver.modals.clearFlag_ ... cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44568402/how-do-i-manually-mouse-dismiss-a-javascript-alert-and-get-back-the-the-body-o/44592827#44592827

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use try catch and if the Alert is not present catch `NoAlertPresentException` exception:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException

try:
    driver.switch_to_alert().accept()
except NoAlertPresentException as e: 
    print("no alert")
```

Comment: name 'NoAlertPresentException' is not defined. this was the output. how do we define it?

Comment: What is the stacktrace?

Comment: Try `selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException` instead of `NoAlertPresentException`

Comment: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\test.py", line 1995, in <module>
    except (NoAlertPresentException) as e:
NameError: name 'NoAlertPresentException' is not defined

Comment: still doesn't work. I'll include all the error messages

Comment: How about importing `from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException `?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77422/discussion-between-halcyon-abraham-ramirez-and-saifur).

Answer (score 4):

This is how you do it:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
try:
    context.driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
except NoAlertPresentException:
    pass
```

You can replace `pass` with a `print` statement if you wish. Note the use of `switch_to.alert` rather than `switch_to_alert()`. The latter has been deprecated for a while. In the version of Selenium I have here, I see this in its code:

```
warnings.warn("use driver.switch_to.alert instead", DeprecationWarning)
```

Comment: May I know why we should not use `switch_to_alert()` ?